# No adapter attached; skipping layout when clicking back button and starting the app again

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

```
Android Studio 3.2 Canary 18
kotlin_version = 1.2.50
```

I have a simple app that uses a recyclerview and adapter. When the app starts is load all the data.
However, when I click the back button and start the app again. It won't display the data (blank).
If I clear the app from memory and start the app. The data will load as normal.

I am loading the data from sqlite and the data is loaded each time. as it populates the `insectDataModelList`.

After going into the `RecyclerView.java` source code the reason is the `mAdapter` is null. However, I have
checked that the adapter is correct when I set it to the recyclerview.

```
void dispatchLayout() {
        if (mAdapter == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "No adapter attached; skipping layout");
            // leave the state in START
            return;
        }
        ...
}
```

My MainActivity.java is Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView rvInsects;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        rvInsects = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        DatabaseManager databaseManager = DatabaseManager.getInstance(this);
        databaseManager.queryAllInsects("friendlyName");
    }

    private void setupAdapter(List<InsectDataModel> insectDataModelList) {
        final LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(
                this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        rvInsects.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        rvInsects.setHasFixedSize(true);
        final InsectAdapter insectAdapter = new InsectAdapter(insectDataModelList);
        rvInsects.setAdapter(insectAdapter);
        insectAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    /* Callback from database */
    public void loadAllInsects(final Cursor cursor) {
        InsectInteractorMapper insectInteractorMapper = new InsectInteractorMapperImp();
        final List<InsectDataModel> insectDataModelList = insectInteractorMapper.map(cursor);
        /* data loaded with 24 items */
        setupAdapter(insectDataModelList);
    }
}
```

InsectAdapter.kt is Kotlin.

```
class InsectAdapter(private val insectList: MutableList<InsectDataModel>)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<InsectAdapter.CustomInsectHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomInsectHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.insect_row_item, parent, false)
        return CustomInsectHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomInsectHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.tvFriendlyName.text = insectList[position].friendlyName
        holder.tvScientificName.text = insectList[position].scientificName
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return insectList.size
    }

    class CustomInsectHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val ivDangerLevel: DangerLevelView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivDangerLevel)
        val tvFriendlyName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFriendlyName)
        val tvScientificName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvScientificName)
    }
}
```

The database I use rxjava2 to do the query

```
public class DatabaseManager {
    private static DatabaseManager sInstance;
    private MainActivity mainActivity;
    private BugsDbHelper mBugsDbHelper;

    public static synchronized DatabaseManager getInstance(MainActivity context) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new DatabaseManager(context);
        }

        return sInstance;
    }

    private DatabaseManager(MainActivity context) {
        mBugsDbHelper = new BugsDbHelper(context);

        mainActivity = context;
    }

    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    public void queryAllInsects(String sortOrder) {
        final InsectStorageInteractorImp insectStorageInteractorImp
                = new InsectStorageInteractorImp(new InsectStorageImp(mBugsDbHelper.getReadableDatabase()));

        insectStorageInteractorImp.getAllSortedInsects(sortOrder)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new SingleObserver<Cursor>() {
                    Disposable disposable;

                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                        disposable = d;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Cursor cursor) {
                        mainActivity.loadAllInsects(cursor);
                        disposable.dispose();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        disposable.dispose();
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Everything works as expected when the apps installs for the first time. And if you clear it out of memory.
However, its only when you click the back button, and then try and start the app it will not load any data
because of the mAdapter being null in the RecyclerView class.

When I click the back button and then start the app again. All I get is a blank screen i.e.

[image]

Updated DatabaseManager class that removes the singleton and used a weakreference to ensure that the MainActivity instance is garbage collected.

```
public class DatabaseManager {
    private WeakReference<MainActivity> mainActivity;
    private BugsDbHelper mBugsDbHelper;

    public DatabaseManager(MainActivity context) {
        mBugsDbHelper = new BugsDbHelper(context);
        mainActivity = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }

    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    public void queryAllInsects(String sortOrder) {
        final InsectStorageInteractorImp insectStorageInteractorImp
                = new InsectStorageInteractorImp(new InsectStorageImp(mBugsDbHelper.getReadableDatabase()));

        insectStorageInteractorImp.getAllSortedInsects(sortOrder)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new SingleObserver<Cursor>() {
                    Disposable disposable;

                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                        disposable = d;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Cursor cursor) {
                        mainActivity.loadAllInsects(cursor);
                        disposable.dispose();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        disposable.dispose();
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: try calling  insectAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in your onResume method.

Comment: Good luck with attestation, sir! 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you click the back button and relaunch the app, a new instance of `MainActivity` is started.

At the same time, your `DatabaseManager` is a **singleton**. Its reference is stored as a *static* variable. It survives the activity recreation. It will live until the process is killed.

So, when you run `queryAllInsects` for the second time, the callback is sent to the **old** instance of `MainActivity`, which is not visible anymore.

You should not keep a reference to `MainActivity` in `DatabaseManager`. It's a *memory leak*, because it cannot be *garbage collected*.

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem and makes perfect sense. I have updated my question with the DatabaseManager class that removes the singleton and uses a weakreference for the MainActivity to ensure that its garbaged collected. Can you see any other problem with this new design? Thanks

Comment: When you call `DatabaseManager.getInstance(this)` for the second time, the reference to the activity is not updated, because `DatabaseManager` already exists. Instead, you can pass a callback to `queryAllInsects`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is most likely that you are loading the data in your onCreate() and not in onResume(). When you press back to "close the app" you are not necessarily clearing the UI stack from memory. That's why when you go back into the app, it doesn't invoke onCreate() again, and doesn't load your data again.

Keep everything the same, just move your data loading from onCreate() to onResume(). That way, whenever the screen is shown to the user, the data will load.

Comment: I moved the data loading from onCreate to onResume. However, I had the same problem and the data is not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Few observations:

1. You are still passing the MainActivity to the BugsDbHelper class, take care of the reference there.
2. It's probably a good idea to include a "cleaning method" in Singleton classes, which should be called in onStop() or onDestroy() of an activity. onStop() is preferred since onDestroy() is not guaranteed to be called immediately.
3. The "cleaning method" in Singleton class should do the following:
   a) Nullify any references to the parameters, objects, context or callbacks you have asked as a dependency in the constructor or otherwise.
   b) If the Singleton class has created "new" objects with context dependencies, make sure to include similar cleaning methods in these classes too.
4. To avoid crashes and memory leakage in fragment/activities, make sure you are cleaning up your recycler view/adapter in onStop(). The callbacks can be received anytime, and if that happens while your activity is in the background, you are bound to get a "force close" fortune cookie.
5. Keep an eye on the activity/fragment lifecycle. A lot of issues are just because of ignoring the lifecycle callbacks. These are there for a reason, utilize them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will take this into account

Answer (score 1):

Put this 2 lines in onResume() and remove from onCreate() and try it.

```
 DatabaseManager databaseManager = DatabaseManager.getInstance(this);
 databaseManager.queryAllInsects("friendlyName");
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following changes:

**MainActivity**, the less code you write in the activity the better, move all the data retrieval part to the `DatabaseManager`. Also setup the `RecyclerView` once and only update the **dataset** when appropriate:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<InsectDataModel> insectDataModelList = new ArrayList<>();

    private Disposable disposable;
    private RecyclerView rvInsects;
    private InsectAdapter insectAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setupAdapter();

        //Request Data, take advantage of RxJava to load data asynchronously
        DatabaseManager.getInstance(this)
                .queryAllInsects("friendlyName")
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new SingleObserver<List<InsectDataModel>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                        disposable = d;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(List<InsectDataModel> response) {
                        insectDataModelList.clear();
                        insectDataModelList.addAll(response);
                        insectAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });;
    }

    private void setupAdapter() {
        //Setup RecyclerView Only need to be called once
        rvInsects = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);    // LinearLayoutManager is Vertical by default
        rvInsects.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);  // You don't event have to define it as RecyclerView use LinearLayoutManager.Vertical by default
        rvInsects.setHasFixedSize(true);
        insectAdapter = new InsectAdapter(insectDataModelList);
        rvInsects.setAdapter(insectAdapter);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        //Dispose observer if activity is destroyed to prevent memory leak
        if(disposable != null && !disposable.isDisposed())
            disposable.dispose();

        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

And in **DatabaseManager**, instead of observing the data source(Cursor) and notify the requester(Activity) via **callback**, we get the data **stream** and pass it the caller to **observe**:

```
public class DatabaseManager {
    private static DatabaseManager sInstance;
    private BugsDbHelper mBugsDbHelper;

    public static synchronized DatabaseManager getInstance() {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new DatabaseManager();
        }

        return sInstance;
    }

    private DatabaseManager() {
        // Move the actualy database initiation to application class or singleton
        mBugsDbHelper = BugsDbHelper.getInstance(); // or ApplicationController.getDbHelper();
    }

    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    public SingleObserver<List<InsectDataModel>> queryAllInsects(String sortOrder) {
        final InsectStorageInteractorImp insectStorageInteractorImp
                = new InsectStorageInteractorImp(new InsectStorageImp(mBugsDbHelper.getReadableDatabase()));

        insectStorageInteractorImp.getAllSortedInsects(sortOrder)
                .map(new Function<Cursor, List<Object>>() {
                    @Override
                    public List<Object> apply(Cursor cursor) throws Exception {
                        InsectInteractorMapper insectInteractorMapper = new InsectInteractorMapperImp();
                        return insectInteractorMapper.map(cursor);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Now the solution here is to rely on the `RxJava` to change the **callback** pattern to the **observer** pattern. So instead of passing the **activity** (callback) and waiting to be called, we get the data **steram** (observable) and **observe** it for the response. This eliminate the leak problem all together and enhance the readability and maintainability.

Also don't forget to move the `Database` **initialization** to the Application class  or a Singleton instance to prevent multiple instantiation. The easier solution would be like:

```
public class ApplicationController extends Application {

    private BugsDbHelper mBugsDbHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mBugsDbHelper = new BugsDbHelper(this);
    }

    public BugsDbHelper getDbHelper(){
        return mBugsDbHelper ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at this. however, I am planning to move the rxJava to the presenter that I will create.